# No module named scipy.stats - Why despite scipy being installed

Tags: python, scipy

How to use python and scipy to get a poissio random variable?  Wow..I installed scipy and per the docs I get No module named scipy.stats?  I am on ubuntu 12.04.  So......go figure

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install python-scipy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-scipy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 482 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from scipy.stats import poisson
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats
```

Comment: is python-scipy version for 3 or 2.7 of python? can you import just scipy?

Comment: Can you ``import scipy``? What's its version?

Comment: try to check what files were installed with `python-scipy`, i think on ubuntu is `dpkg -L python-scipy`

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy-0.9.0.egg-info

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think scipy is the way to go.  Probably you have a simple namespace visibility problem.  since stats is itself a module you first need to import it, then you can use functions from scipy.stats

```
import scipy
import scipy.stats
#now you can use
scipy.stats.poisson
#if you want it more accessible you could do what you did above
from scipy.stats import poisson
#then call poisson directly
poisson
```

Answer (score 4):

pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall scipy

Comment: Please provide a description, not necessarily even a long one

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally caused this issue by naming one of my scipy test programs "scipy.py".  Of course, this makes any "import scipy" in this directory import my test program, not the system library, in turn resulting in lots of errors like:

```
ImportError: No module named stats
```

It's embarrassing how long it took me to figure this out!

Comment: Creating a file called "new.py" seems to have a similar effect (that was my mistake).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Python 3.4 on my Windows 7 machine. I had to update my scipy package 'pip install --upgrade scipy'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the install issue is, perhaps consider installing [Enthought Canopy or EPD](https://www.enthought.com/downloads/)? It handles all of the packages and dependencies nicely.

Alternatively, if you just want to do some stats, try installing [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/).