# ImportError on scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy, package, python-import, importerror

I am trying to use a python program, which requires scipy dependency. The `scipy` dependency is installed, but I need to call `scipy.stats` and then `binom` which is within `scipy`.

I tried the method in these answers:

[Import scipy.stats error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469734/import-scipy-stats-error)

[No module named scipy.stats - Why despite scipy being installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261077/no-module-named-scipy-stats-why-despite-scipy-being-installed)

```
>>> import scipy
>>> import scipy.stats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named stats
>>> from scipy import stats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name stats
>>> from scipy.stats import binom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named stats
```

I am not a sudo user and cannot rename a file, but the filename shouldn’t be the problem as it is used in a frequently used server.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Once you imported scipy, say, `as sc`, what about playing directly with `sc.stats.binom`?

Comment: @Kanak That won't work.  `import scipy` does not import all the subpackages.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. It does work for me.

Comment: @Kanak Are you saying if the only two statements in a script are `import scipy as sc; print(sc.stats)` you don't get an error?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. Ok. At first I though I had a `from .stats import *` in scipy/__init__.py, which would have explained why I got no error. Actually the script that led me to think that `import scipy as sc;sc.stats` was universally working, relies on [PySAL](http://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). In one of its script, i.e. [common.py](https://pypkg.com/pypi/pysal/f/pysal/common.py) it reads `import scipy as sp;import scipy.stats as stats`. And doing `print(sp.stats)` afterwards fallaciously works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Python-CLI try the following:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version__
'1.0.0'
>>> scipy.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py'
```

Look if your output looks anything similar to this one. If `scipy.__file__` points to a private directory of yours, then you have to resolve that namespace problem by renaming your own package.
In case it looks similar, then in another terminal move into that directory:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/
ls
```

Look for a folder called `stats/`, if it is missing then your scipy is not installed correctly and you should reinstall it.

Comment: What if the `stats/` folder exists in the right path but still the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stats'` error appears? Thanks

Comment: @Metafaniel i keep getting this error what did you do to resolve this?

Comment: @d3hero23 Time has passed since then and, to be honest, I can hardly remember what is this all about. Also in my comment, I was asking something so most likely I didn't find out. Sorry and good luck!